# How to apply wildcard on a list of directories

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching, wildcard

I've this directory structure:

- root/

  - build/  `#I'm inside this directory`
  - dir1/

    - build

      - obj `#.o files inside this`
  - dir2/

    - build

      - obj `#.o files inside this`
  - dir3/

    - build

      - obj `#.o files inside this`

As you see my makefile is in `root/build` — the makefile defines a variable as:

```
DIRS = dir1 dir2 dir3  #there could be many
```

and then I try to create a variable as:

```
OBJDIRS = $(DIRS:%=../%/build/obj)
$(info $(OBJDIRS))                  #lets print the list
```

Here `info` prints this list:

```
../dir1/build/obj ../dir2/build/obj ../dir3/build/obj
```

Now I want to get a list of all the object files inside `obj` directories of all the `dir*` directories. How to get that? I tried this:

```
OBJECTS = $(wildcard $(OBJDIRS)/*.o)
$(info $(OBJECTS))
```

which prints this only:

```
../dir1/build/obj
```

The `wildcard` doesn't seem to work on a list of directories. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two things wrong with your current attempt.

1. `$(wildcard)` doesn't use <kbd>%</kbd> as its wildcard character. It uses <kbd>*</kbd>. So you need `$(wildcard $(OBJDIRS)/*.o)` to fix that.
2. `$(OBJDIRS)/*.o` is going to expand into `../dir1/build/obj ../dir2/build/obj ../dir3/build/obj/*.o`. Which, you'll notice, isn't what you want. So you need to use `$(addsuffix /*.o,$(OBJDIRS))` or another substitution to generate the list of wildcard patterns you want.

Comment: 1. Oops `%` is a typo. I fixed it. My makefile tried both `%` and `*`. The result is same in both cases. 2. I see.

Comment: With a `*` wildcard I'd have expected the `$(wildcard) call to have listed the `dir1` entry and anything that matched under `dir3` (or whatever other path was last.